# npm run start:dev says localhost refused to connect, but gives no errors to the console

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am trying to create a project through nestjs. I have created my project and have not edited anything inside of it yet, but when I run `npm run start:dev` it runs like it is supposed to in the console, but nothing happens when I go to http://localhost:3000. I can run `npm run start` without any issues, but I want the project to automatically update when it detects changes. Why does one work but the other doesn't? I will paste the scripts from my package.json file below:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  }
```

Comment: can you share the output of `npx nest info`

Comment: Here is the output of npx nest info:
[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 10.0.3

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-express version : 10.0.2
schematics version       : 10.0.1
testing version          : 10.0.2
common version           : 10.0.2
core version             : 10.0.2
cli version              : 10.0.3

Comment: are you using windows or what?

Comment: also, which version of `typescript` are you using? see `npm ls typescript`

Comment: Yes, I am using windows. And I am using typescript version 5.1.3

Comment: might be related to this: https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#file-change-detected-loops-endlessly

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by replacing all of the scripts in my package.json file as seen below. Not sure what the issue was, but it seems to be working now.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/main",
    "start:dev": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --exec ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 src/main.ts",
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  }
```